# Can we bundle a directory inside apk file?

Tags: android

I have a directory which contains some files. I want to bundle this directory inside apk file so that when I install apk file the directory gets copied to a particular location on the android device.

Can I bundle a directory inside apk file as I didn't find this information on developer.android.com? Do I need to modify any configuration file for this?

Thanks..
Ajay

Answer (score 3):

You cant, but you could take a look at the android assets folder,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Assets are raw resources, they won't be compressed by the android compiler.

From the developers site:

**assets/**

> This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you
>   save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original
>   filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way
>   as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of
>   bytes using the the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location
>   for textures and game data.

Comment: +1 Worth Noting: This solution doesn't allow to later update these files; either by getting newer version from the web or by making changes from the software interface

Comment: You could copy those assets files to an android directory on the first start of your app, this would allow changes to the files.

Comment: thanks for the details. as you mentioned, i can copy the files on the first start of app but i wanted this to happen at the time of apk installation. as of now i'm not sure whether it is possible, i carried out a small test and it didn't work. I created a folder containing some files under assets/ folder. I built my java app from eclipse and it created a apk file. I ran this app from android device but didn't find my folder on the device, the application got installed though. i think this folder is still not the part of apk which got installed on the device.

Comment: It is not possible at the moment that's the point here :(. You have two options, copy the files or don't copy them and leave them in the assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

The `assets/` folder in apk is intended to store any extra user files in any formats. They will be included to apk automatically on compilation stage and can be accessed from the app using `getAssets()` function.

Comment: Jaguar, I carried out a small test and it didn't work. I created a folder containing some files under assets/ folder. I built my java app from eclipse and it created a apk file. I ran this app from android device but didn't find my folder on the device, the application got installed though. i think this folder is still not the part of apk which got installed on the device. do you know how to copy this folder to the device during apk installation? i'm not sure if it is possible.